# Unicode search not working

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-unicode

Consider this.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
data = "cdbsb \xe2\x80\xa6 abc"
print data 
#prints cdbsb … abc
              ^
print re.findall(ur"[\u2026]", data )
```

Why can't `re` find this unicode character ? I have already checked

```
\xe2\x80\xa6 === … === U+2026
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go through the link provided by [nhahtdh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1400768/nhahtdh)

[Solving Unicode Problems in Python 2.7](http://www.azavea.com/blogs/labs/2014/03/solving-unicode-problems-in-python-2-7/)

You can see the original string was in `bytes` and we were searching for unicode. So it should never have worked.

> `encode()`: Gets you from Unicode → bytes
>
> `decode()`: Gets you from bytes → Unicode

Following these we can solve it in 2 ways.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
data = "cdbsb \xe2\x80\xa6 abc".decode("utf-8")  #convert to unicode
print data
print re.findall(ur"[\u2026]", data )
print re.findall(ur"[\u2026]", data )[0].encode("utf-8")  #compare with unicode byte string and then reconvert to bytes for print

data1 = "cdbsb \xe2\x80\xa6 abc"  #let it remain bytes
print data1
print re.findall(r"\xe2\x80\xa6", data1 )[0] #search for bytes
```

Comment: Personally, I find no reason to use the 2nd method. In Python 2, one should always use `unicode` type if they are dealing with character data. Using `str` may hide error when you use literal Unicode character in the regex source code.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the issue is because `data` is a byte-string. You might have the console encoding as `utf-8` , hence when printing the string, the console converts the string to `utf-8` and then shows it (You can check this out at `sys.stdout.encoding` ). Hence you are getting the character - `…` .

But most probably `re` does not do this decoding for you.

If you convert `data` to `utf-8` encoding, you would get the desired result when using `re.findall`. Example -

```
>>> data = "cdbsb \xe2\x80\xa6 abc"
>>> print re.findall(ur"[\u2026]", data.decode('utf-8') )
[u'\u2026']
```

Comment: You mean to say `print` automatically does that?Also it again doesnt print `…`

Comment: Actually it converts to the encoding used by the console - `sys.stdout.encoding` .

Comment: @vks I am trying to find some reference for that . Till now I could only find - https://wiki.python.org/moin/PrintFails .

Comment: @vks I believe it would be the console doing the decoding/encoding, not Python

Comment: Don't know if this helps but `if u"\u2026".encode('utf8') in data: print True` works for me ;)

Comment: @RolfofSaxony: This is just a minimal example. What if you have many character to check?

Comment: @nhahtdh It's a minimal comment, in the same vein as the questions `print re.findall(ur"[\u2026]", data )`

Answer (score 1):

`data` is of **str** type and contains ASCII character with hex value. But the search term is of **unicode** type . Print function converts default to `sys.stdout.encoding`. When I try to print `data` as it is, the output differs from `data.decode('utf-8')`. I am using Python 2.7

```
data = "cdbsb \xe2\x80\xa6 abc"
search = ur"[\u2026]"

print sys.stdout.encoding
## windows-1254

print data, type(data)
## cdbsb â€¦ abc <type 'str'>

print data.decode(sys.stdout.encoding)
## cdbsb â€¦ abc

print data.decode('utf-8')
## cdbsb … abc

print search, type(search)
## […] <type 'unicode'>

print re.findall(search, data.decode('utf-8'))
## [u'\u2026']
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution:

```
>>> data = "cdbsb \xe2\x80\xa6 abc"
>>> print data 
cdbsb … abc
>>> if u"\u2026".encode('utf8') in data: print True
... 
True
>>> if u"\u2026" in data.decode('utf8'): print True
... 
True
```