# use character like 'ë' and 'ç' in python file

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, character-encoding

Inside a list and  I have to use special characters like this: 'ë' and 'ç', inside a python file.
My list looks like:

```
mylist = ['Deçan','Dragashë','Ferizaj',"Fushë ",'Gjakovë' ]
```

but I get an  error: `SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file ...`

Even if I pre-encode them like(&euml ; for  'ë') I get the same error.How can I use those characters?

Comment: That error message contains a link which tells you *exactly* what code you need to insert to make it work. Did you try and follow it?

Comment: @DanielRoseman i followed those instructions but I couldn't fix this!

Comment: but it told you what to use instead in the message...

Comment: So, what did you put in your file as a result of the instructions?

Comment: @TomTanner following https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ i tried to use: # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- or #coding: utf-8 but nothing new, the same error!

Comment: Your code work fine for me in Python 2.6.6 if I put `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` as the second line of the script.

Comment: @PM2Ring  i'm using Python 2.7, if I put # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- as the first line of the script i'm getting another error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)?

Comment: BTW, `&euml;` is a HTML entity, it means nothing to the Python parser (although there are Python libraries that can handle such entities), so you can't use HTML entities to encode string literals in your Python source code. OTOH, you _can_ use hexadecimal escape codes like `u'De\xe7an'` and `u'Dragash\xeb'`

Comment: @PM2Ring thank you for your answer!

Comment: You may find this article helpful: [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Comment: So I got here from meta stack overflow using this question to make a point. The first comment should provide the link because me looking at this question cannot do anything else. So my take away is OP cannot follow basic instructions and the commentators cannot provide useful comments for the people reaching this question from google - but they are great at making people look like idiots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `unicode` strings if you are generating them or decode them to unicode if you getting them from somewhere.

```
mylist = [u'De\u00E7an',u'Dragash\u00EB',u'Ferizaj',u"Fush\u00EB ",u'Gjakov\u00EB' ]
print mylist[0],mylist[1]
```

Now you can work with these safely encoding,decoding as per your needs

Comment: thank you for your answer! where is the difference between u'De\u00E7an' and  u'De\xe7an'?

Comment: @EgzontinaK you can encode to `utf-8` and get the hexa part

Comment: @EgzontinaK `u` is unicode `x` is hex code....read more here....http://www.azavea.com/blogs/labs/2014/03/solving-unicode-problems-in-python-2-7/

Comment: @EgzontinaK also go thru this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33031009/unicode-search-not-working

Comment: @EgzontinaK there's absolutely no difference between `u'De\u00E7an'`, `u'De\xe7an'`, and `u'De\U000000e7an'`, except for the number of digits needed to specify the character. All of the examples in this answer could have used `\x` instead of `\u` since the leading digits are all zeros.

Comment: @MarkRansom not exactly same.....unicode mapping is differernt than byte mapping which depends on encoding it is being subjected too...here it was naive though :)

Comment: @vks I'm quite sure that those will be identical if they're used inside a *Unicode* string. Note that all my examples started with `u'`, as did yours.

Comment: @MarkRansom using both those example I can't save on my mongo db database!

Comment: @EgzontinaK that sounds like a new question.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
#coding: utf-8

mylist = ['Deçan','Dragashë','Ferizaj',"Fushë ",'Gjakovë' ]
```

Here `#coding: utf-8` specifies the encoding of the file.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error: SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file ..

Comment: @EgzontinaK that would be because your file is not UTF-8 as many would assume. Try `mbcs` instead.

Comment: Uhm, shouldn't this be `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` in the very first line?

Comment: @Ani, there's no difference so you can use any of them

Answer (score 0):

Your project encoding should be UTF-8. For example I use Pycharm and set IDE and prodect encodings to UTF-8.

```
mylist = ['Deçan','Dragashë','Ferizaj',"Fushë ",'Gjakovë' ]
for el in mylist:
    print(el)

Deçan
Dragashë
Ferizaj
Fushë 
Gjakovë
```

Comment: @you have to look into settings and change the encoding to UTF-8

Comment: @EgzontinaK check here http://superuser.com/questions/581553/sublime-text-2-encoding-utf-8

Answer (score 0):

If you would rather use the actual characters in your strings instead of escape sequences, you need to make sure your source file encoding is set properly. Most advice you will see on this will insist that you need UTF-8 encoded files, but that's not true - what matters is that the encoding you specify at the top of the source file is the encoding you're actually using. For Windows in particular your PC will be configured with a [code page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page) that tells how each byte value should be converted to a character by default.

In Python the special encoding `mbcs` can be used to specify the current Windows default code page. Note that the `#coding` comment must be the first line of the file, or the second line if a `#!` comes first.

```
#coding: mbcs

mylist = ['Deçan','Dragashë','Ferizaj',"Fushë ",'Gjakovë' ]
```